# Do you need micro and bloom formulas for plants without fruit?

Tags: hydroponic

The liquid fertiliser I want to use is a three part formula, grow, micro and bloom. I intend to only cultivate plants that dont fruit, like most kinds of leafy veg. Is it then ok to omit the micro and bloom formulas from the feeding schedule.

Just for reference Im using  EHG grow formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always need micro and you won't need bloom if you aren't growing fruiting plants. So can just use micro and grow for leafy veg.